# Hibernate in query in 2 different columns?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am  trying to find rows that has one of the values  I am  looking for in one of the 2 columns. So far I've used a criteria like this but it doesn't find anything.

```
Criterion a = Restrictions.in("oid", workOrderOids);

Criterion b = Restrictions.in("parentReworkOid", workOrderOids);

Criterion c = Restrictions.or(a, b);
```

What might i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `disjunction` here.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
disjunction.add(Restrictions.in("oid", workOrderOids));
disjunction.add(Restrictions.in("parentReworkOid", workOrderOids));
// add others if any
crit.add(disjunction);
```

Comment: Thanks I found the main source of the problem. It was happening because there were null values in one of my columns so "in" clause was returning true all the time.